# How to undo/revert "npm audit fix"

Tags: npm

As the title says. I have run `npm audit fix` in cmd. Now I can't run `npm run build` as it gives me errors. How to undo `npm audit fix`? Is there such command?

After running `npm audit fix` I get this errors:

```
D:\SUBLIME\REACT>npm run build

> uploadpublish@1.0.0 build D:\SUBLIME\REACT
> webpack --mode production

D:\SUBLIME\REACT\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\config-yargs.js:136
                                describe: optionsSchema.definitions.output.properties.path.description
                                                                           ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'properties' of undefined
    at module.exports (D:\SUBLIME\REACT\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\config-yargs.js:13
    at D:\SUBLIME\REACT\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\webpack.js:59:27
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\SUBLIME\REACT\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\webpack.js:514
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! uploadpublish@1.0.0 build: `webpack --mode production`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the uploadpublish@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\VERYNICE\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-06-10T14_43_53_493Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Just revert the commit (or reset if you didn't commit it) and run `npm ci` again?

Comment: If you have checked out your files from git or downloaded your project, you just need to revert `package-lock.json` to the previous state. Run npm install and you're good to go.

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not understand you guys. I am quite noob with npm atm. Can I simply run some kind of command in cmd for e.g "revert npm audit fix" and it goes all back or not?

Comment: What errors are they?

Comment: Edited them in my initial post

Answer (score 12):

I had a slightly different problem. I ran `npm audit fix --force` while developing my app, and my project failed to compile when I tried to run `npm start`. I saw the previous answer, and found more information about `npm audit`in [this article on Overreacted](https://overreacted.io/npm-audit-broken-by-design/).

I ran `git status` to make sure the changes to package.json and package-lock.json were not yet staged for commit. Then, I ran `git restore package-lock.json` and `git restore package.json`. Then, I ran `npm install` again, and the app was able to compile.

Comment: It works, but it will restore all package.json to its last state, Means if you're if you have many packages installed can remove them if didn't commited.

Answer (score 11):

Unfortunately, an undo function does not exist in **npm**, so keeping the previous state of the `package.json` file and, if present, the `package-lock.json` and the `npm-shrinkwrap.json` (these files are optionally) to restore it via `npm install` (or short: `npm i`) is the way to go.

Normally, in a situation like yours, you would simply revert all changes to `package.json` and `package-lock.json` with a version control system like [**git**](https://git-scm.com/). Of course, you can do this manually, too, if you have saved the previous version of these files somewhere. A present `npm-shrinkwrap.json` file is not affected by an `npm update` and therefor must not be restored.

Afterwards you can install the old version of your project's dependencies with `npm i`.
Keep in mind, that the package-lock.json takes precedence over package.json and the `package.json` file uses **Semantic Versioning** (semver). And the `npm-shrinkwrap.json` file takes precedence over both files. There are even some more subtle differences, but I think this goes too far for this answer.

For more details, you can refer to these docs:

- [`npm install`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)
- [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/configuring-npm/package-json.html)
- [package-lock.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/configuring-npm/package-lock-json.html)
- [npm-shrinkwrap.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/configuring-npm/shrinkwrap-json.html)

So I hope you have a backup or a previous git commit somewhere. Otherwise you could try to resolve the error by trying to read the error message and use an older version of the package which throws this error (`webpack` in you case). Also the dependencies of this package could be the reason for the problem. But take your time, if you decide to go this way. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 6):

I manually copied my package.json and package.lock.json from my previous commit, then I did an 'npm install' and rebuilt my React native app. It worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar kind of problem. while I developing my app I ran the command "npm audit fix --force". It upgraded all my dependencies and could not run my app.
What I did was in the below to fix the problem

1. first I deleted both package.json and package-lock.json
2. then also deleted node_modules folder.
3. then restore the previous version of package.json, package-lock.josn and node_modules folder. (to restore process you can use a version controller like Git)

thats worked well with my issue.

Comment: Yooo, you are committing your node_modules folder?

Comment: no need. just install node_modules uisng "npm install". it install the dependencies in the 'package.json'

Answer (score 0):

Try-
$npm uninstall react-scripts

And install it again-
$npm install react-scrip

Actually npm audit will change your react-scripts version