# SASS module installation failed. Unable to run React app

Tags: reactjs, sass

SASS used to work but not working after I ran $ npm audit fix --force. Seems like my node environment got messed up, If repairing the current environment difficult, how can we restore / reset the node installation ?

Installed sass module again. ($npm install -g sass)
Created a simple index.scss file, once i save i get this below error in the browser.

```
    Compiled with problems:

ERROR in ./src/index.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[7].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[7].use[2]!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[7].use[3]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[7].use[4]!./src/index.scss)

Module Error (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Cannot find module 'sass'
Require stack:
- /Users/vikramkumarchindam/react/z2m/capstone/routing-example/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/utils.js
- /Users/vikramkumarchindam/react/z2m/capstone/routing-example/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/index.js
- /Users/vikramkumarchindam/react/z2m/capstone/routing-example/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js
- /Users/vikramkumarchindam/react/z2m/capstone/routing-example/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js
- /Users/vikramkumarchindam/react/z2m/capstone/routing-example/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js
- /Users/vikramkumarchindam/react/z2m/capstone/routing-example/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js
- /Users/vikramkumarchindam/react/z2m/capstone/routing-example/node_modules/webpack-manifest-plugin/dist/index.js
- /Users/vikramkumarchindam/react/z2m/capstone/routing-example/node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js
- /Users/vikramkumarchindam/react/z2m/capstone/routing-example/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js


ERROR in ./src/index.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[7].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[7].use[2]!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[7].use[3]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[7].use[4]!./src/index.scss)

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js):
Error: resolve-url-loader: error processing CSS
  PostCSS received undefined instead of CSS string
  at new Input (/Users/vikramkumarchindam/react/z2m/capstone/routing-example/node_modules/resolve-url-loader/node_modules/postcss/lib/input.js:38:13)
    at encodeError (/Users/vikramkumarchindam/react/z2m/capstone/routing-example/node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js:287:12)
    at onFailure (/Users/vikramkumarchindam/react/z2m/capstone/routing-example/node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js:228:14)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to undo/revert "npm audit fix"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62306016/how-to-undo-revert-npm-audit-fix)

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install sass-loader@10 node-sass --save-dev
```